# Anyone know of an iphone tutorial for managing hierarchical data?

Tags: iphone, sdk

For example, let's say you have a list with elements {A,B,C}

and you click on A and it gives you a list of elements that belong to A which might be {J,K,Z}, and if you click on B it gives you a list of elements that belongs to B which might be {D,E}, etc.

Any advice would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To store the data you can use NSDictionary. To create the UI, you can use table view recursively.